# JeasyOpc Problem, how to connect to other computers in LAN using JeasyOpc client?

Tags: java, opc, jeasyopc

I made a program basing on JeasyOpc source code, whan i try to use it on localhost there is no problem it works fine (i can see the opc server and can read signals from it). Than i tried to read signals from a another computer in our Lan - not working. I configured the DCOM as required but nothing helps. I even downloaded a trial version of Matrikon Opc tunneler it helps to detect opc servers on Lan with other opc browsers(otherwise they couldn't detect), but not with my JeasyOpc basing program. Please Help!

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like OpcEnum is not configured correctly.

1. Make sure OpcEnum isn't listed in Window's Firewall. It doesn't matter how correct your DCOM settings are if the firewall is blocking access.
2. Start with authentication levels set to none, and add security slowly.
   [image]
3. Make sure both computers part of the same workgroup/domain.
4. Enable file-sharing for the computers. This has fixed some problems I've experienced with OPC in the past. I'm guessing it toggles some DCOM setting somewhere. Don't ask me exactly why this works.